# Android 1.6 TabHost inside a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, android-support-library

In the demo [Support4Demos - API 4+ Support Demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/index.html) , the Tabs and TabsPager examples both extend FragmentActivity. Each tab content is itself a Fragment. No real breakthrough, TabActivity was used the same way without the introduction of Fragment.

Now suppose inside my Activity , a screen portion is a Fragment named WidgetFragment. How is it possible for WidgetFragment to contain a TabHost ? Visualize a mini TabHost contained inside an Activity.
I tried every possible way to insert a TabHost inside a Fragment not a FragmentActivity.

Comment: And when you tried "every possible way", what happened?

Comment: did not work, that's why I'm asking :) . Tried to implement it inside a Fragment like it's done inside a FragmentActivity in the demo.

Comment: Please define "did not work".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In generally accepted practices, Tabs fit the whole screen. 
Most people (including me) are unaware the tabs can be placed anywhere like a simple view, ListView.
The trick is to include your TabHost inside another layout. When you create the TabHost, always keep these id : **tabhost , tabs , tabcontent**

In your main layout, include your tabhost.xml . Here I center the TabHost in the middle

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Fill whatever you need -->     
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/widget_fragment"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <include layout="@layout/tabhost" />
    </FrameLayout> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Look well at the Tabs and TabsPager examples in  Support4Demos , the TabHost is still managed by FragmentActivity. Each tab content is a fragment. With TabActivity, it may not be possible to have a tab anywhere

At the end, this is what it looks like

[image]