# List-view with fragments using tab host?

Tags: android

Guys,

```
     I have tried different samples using the list-view with fragments,In my application i am using list-view, tab-host,fragments.
```

1.when i clicked on the tab-host, it need to display the list-view, The list-view need to be extended with fragments.

Thanks in advance!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

refer this link for details

[Android 1.6 TabHost inside a Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285331/android-1-6-tabhost-inside-a-fragment)

http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-tabs-with-fragments/

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html