# Android fragments: replace fragment from other fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

It is possiable to make this UI arcitrcture:

```
                    |-Fragment A              |-Tab A (Fragment)
                    |                         |
Fragment Activity <-|-Fragment with Tabhost <-|-Tab B (Fragment)
                    |                         |
                    |-Fragment B              |-Tab C (Fragment)
```

Fragment A, B Fragment with Tabhost place in FrameActivity directly. Tabs A, B and C plase in fragment with Tabhost.

Tab Fragment mast have ability to replace fragment with Tabhost to other fragment (A or B).

It is possible to make? May be exists good example? Thanks!

Comment: Please take a look at a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285331/android-1-6-tabhost-inside-a-fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know you cannot add fragments into fragments.In design document it's written that 
"A fragment must always be embedded in an activity and the fragment's lifecycle is directly affected by the host activity's lifecycle." So your design seems like impossible to develop for now.