# Using Action bar inside a Fragment

Tags: android-fragments, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to create action bar inside the Fragment..

The layout should be like this

```
   __________________________
  |<Icon>Title               |
   ==========================
  |Name: Albert              |
  |Country: Indonesia        |
  |                          |
   ==========================
  |  Home  |  News  | Google |
  |                          |
  |                          |
  |                          |
  |                          | 
  |                          | 
  |                          | 
  |                          | 
  |                          | 
  |                          | 
  |                          | 
  |                          | 
   --------------------------
```

Now i have fragment on the top for Profile
And Fragment in the bottom..

But i have problem about how to make the bottom fragment becomes tabbed..

Anyone can help? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are trying to make tabs? or make a gap with info between the tabs?

Comment: I am trying to make tabs.. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Check this out - http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/761642-android-app-development-for-beginners-navigation-with-tabs if you want it in fragment - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html next time, try research online a bit before posting a question.
Good luck with you app. Update:
Here is the link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285331/android-1-6-tabhost-inside-a-fragment